# Continuous Image Vertical Scroller

Tags: javascript, image, scroll, infinite-loop, marquee

I need to adjust the script from http://javascript.about.com/library/blcvert.htm to change direction of scrolling to DOWN.

Could anybody help?

Of course, it would be also helpful if anybody knows/have some other script which produces the same effect.

Thanx

P.S. the script (in readable format is):

```
    var imgAry1 = ['img1.png','img2.png'];

    function startCloud() {
       new mq('clouds', imgAry1, 380);
       mqRotate(mqr);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        startCloud();
    });

    var mqr = [];

    function mq(id, ary, heit) {
    this.mqo=document.getElementById(id);
    var wid = this.mqo.style.width;
    this.mqo.onmouseout=function() { mqRotate(mqr); };
    this.mqo.onmouseover=function() { clearTimeout(mqr[0].TO); };
    this.mqo.ary=[];
    var maxw = ary.length;
    for (var i=0;i<maxw;i++) {
        this.mqo.ary[i]=document.createElement('img');
        this.mqo.ary[i].src=ary[i];
        this.mqo.ary[i].style.position = 'absolute';
        this.mqo.ary[i].style.top = (heit*i)+'px';
        this.mqo.ary[i].style.height = heit+'px';
        this.mqo.ary[i].style.width = wid;
        this.mqo.appendChild(this.mqo.ary[i]);
    }
    mqr.push(this.mqo);
    }

    function mqRotate(mqr) {
    if (!mqr) return;
    for (var j=mqr.length - 1; j > -1; j--) {
        maxa = mqr[j].ary.length;
        for (var i=0;i<maxa;i++) {
            var x = mqr[j].ary[i].style;
            x.top=(parseInt(x.top,10)-1)+'px';
        }
        var y = mqr[j].ary[0].style;
        if (parseInt(y.top,10)+parseInt(y.height,10)<0) {
            var z = mqr[j].ary.shift();
            z.style.top = (parseInt(z.style.top) + parseInt(z.style.height)*maxa) + 'px';
            mqr[j].ary.push(z);
        }
    }
    mqr[0].TO=setTimeout('mqRotate(mqr)',10);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

`x.top=(parseInt(x.top,10)-1)+'px';`

it says that you take `x.top` in pixels, parse out the number, **subtract** one and add the 'px' again. The element's position from top is **decreased** by 1 each time, so it goes **up**. All you need to do for it to go **down** is to **add** the one.

`x.top=(parseInt(x.top,10)+1)+'px';`

I also tested this hypothesis on the page you linked :)